# How to determine the functions available in DLL for use in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, labview

A [LabView dll file](http://www.brooksinstrument.com/products/accessories-software/product-software/brooks-labview-dll) is to be used from a Python 2.7 script. What can we do to figure out which are the methods in the DLL file that we can call from Python, without having to load the dll in LabView?

Also, do I need to have LabView running on the system which runs the Python code that calls the LabView dll?

Comment: Not sure I'm getting the question. You could `nm thedll.dll` in a command prompt and see the symbols.

Comment: In general I would advise against attempting to call a LabVIEW DLL from python. If the DLL is a pure C DLL, then it should work as a normal standalone library. If, however, the manufacturer has linked with labview.lib, and uses it's memory allocation methods (e.g creating or resizing handles) this is not going to work.

Comment: For the avoidance of confusion, it looks as if this 'LabVIEW DLL' is a DLL intended to be used *from* LabVIEW, not a DLL created *in* LabVIEW. Have you tried asking the manufacturer what the methods are and whether they should be callable from other languages?

Comment: @nekomatic I need my Python script to communicate with a device using the HART protocol, but I can't find any Python libraries for HART, so the next best thing is to use a LabVIEW DLL provided by manufacturer...

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is, that you are using a third party DLL created with LabView. In this case the LabView runtime has to be installed to use it which can be installed for free: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/B727BE0152F606D486256A22004DE82D

To find the methods provided with the DLL I would

- Search for a documentation by the manufacturer
- Look for a header file provided with the DLL
- Use a Tool like DLL Export Viewer: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html